# null view reference in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in my app with 4 fragments. One of my fragments has a public method that returns a value from a spinner.

But sometimes when I call the method on the fragment reference I get a nullpointerexception:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.Spinner.getSelectedItem()' on a null object reference
```

And this is the method that I call on the fragment:

```
public String getCategoryId() {
    if (spVendorCategories.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        String categoryId = 
            ((VendorCategory) spVendorCategories.getSelectedItem()).getId();
            return categoryId;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The crash happens in the second line.

I create the fragment in my activity in onCreate:

```
GeneralSettingsFragment generalSettingsFragment = GeneralSettingsFragment.newInstance(generalSettings);
```

And then I get the value in an onClick event method:

```
@OnClick(R.id.save_vendor_settings_button)
void onSaveVendorSettingsButtonClick() {
    if (generalSettingsFragment != null) {
        String categoryId = generalSettingsFragment.getCategoryId();
        // rest of the code
    }
}
```

Looks like the spinner reference variable is nulled but I don't why and how to prevent it.

BTW I use ButterKnife and I also set my viewpager's offscreen page limit to 4.

Comment: Could you post your Fragment code and the usage please?

Comment: there is likely a problem with your code. Sorry for obvious note, but nothing more to say without seeing your code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko You're right. I posted the code.

Comment: Show where and how you write to `spVendorCategories`

Comment: And also where you use the `getCategoryId()`

Comment: This is obvious. Your method is public and you are calling that method even when fragment is not on screen. It says Spinner is not present

Comment: creating a fragment does not create it's view. It has it's lifecycle, where it's view is created. You can't use it's view before it is created.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko so how can I make sure that the view is also created before calling the getCategoryId method?

Comment: you could use a flag like `public boolean viewCreated` in your fragment, and set it to `true` after view is created. Or get the view directly, and check if it is null

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko so generalSettingsFragment.getView() != null will do the trick?

Comment: yes, should do.

Comment: @Mostafa this crash is happening because you are accessing spinner even before the view is created. In order to get rid of this you need to use spinner after the view is created. As suggested by Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

In that 2nd line change to `if (isAdded() && generalSettingsFragment != null)`

Keep tracking is fragment is attached, so its view is not null

Comment: Can't there be any situation that the fragment is attached but it's view is null?

Comment: It is possible, since oncreateview is being triggered after onAttach, so just add check for that one also